# Como saber o numero da linha em que o ID foi exibido

Tags: php

O problema é o seguinte. 
Eu tenho um while que pega valores no banco de dados:

```
...
while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>autor:".$produto['user_of'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['categ'] . "</td>";
        ...
```

Agora, como posso ter o numero da posição da linha em que o elemento ID=10 é exibido?

Comment: Tentou criar um contador? Qual é a finalidade de saber o número da linha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O jeito simples de se fazer seria criar uma `variável` contadora.

Ex:

```
$numLinhas = 0;
while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>autor:".$produto['user_of'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$produto['categ'] . "</td>";
        $numLinhas++;

        //para mostrar a linha
        if($produto['id'] == 10)
            echo "Numero da linha: ".$numLinhas;

        //para jogar para outra váriavel
        if($produto['id'] == 10)
            $posicaoID = $numLinhas
}
```

Comment: simples! obrigado!!